# build list of buttons like in the picture

Tags: iphone, list, presentmodalviewcontroller, slideup

am trying to build buttons list slides from bottom  of screen when some button pressed

what's it's name ?!

i tried to build a view with 200px height and then inserting it via

```
ShareViewController * svc=[[ShareViewController alloc ]initWithNibName:@"ShareViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES];
```

but it down't work ?!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is standard [UIActionSheet](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html&ei=DlR3ToXjFMig4gTlusizDQ&usg=AFQjCNHV1MXOfgqZCX1AbUg4KTQdlvcXiQ&sig2=N8htBGLp3Mbf4ECVgSavTA) control which goes with UIKit, so you don't need to create extra controllers to achieve the effect you want.

Answer (score 2):

Like @Vladimir said, you are looking at a UIActionSheet. If you are actually trying to build that exact one, you should know it comes from ShareKit: http://getsharekit.com/